# How to start FusedLocationProvider from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I implemented FusedLocation provider to retrieve location periodically, which runs on ForegroundService. This works fine when provider is started if the app is opened.

Then I have BoradcastReceiver which runs on background and periodically checks the status on the server and based on that starts or stops the FusedLocation provider. My issue is when I start FusedLocation provider form BroadcastReceiver it is started, but I don't receive any locations. I also tried LocationManager and having the same problem.

I tested BroadcastReceiver and it periodically checks the status until it enters Doze mode. This leads me to a question if I can start FusedLocation provider from other thread than main thread?

**This is how I start the BroadcastReceiver:**

```
        var mainActivity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        var alarmIntent = new Intent(mainActivity.ApplicationContext, typeof(UpdateInfoReceiver));
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(mainActivity.ApplicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mainActivity.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        alarmManager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.IntervalFifteenMinutes,  AlarmManager.IntervalFifteenMinutes, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: yes, you can. I experienced using fusedLocation provider in other thread but in my case, this thread was started by a ForegroundService. Make sure your thread is really started, RequestLocationUpdates() is called.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by background access limits.
Check this - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

If you need to access location frequently - use Foreground Service.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I run it on ForegroundService.